# How to implement plain javascript code to validate a logical expression string with variables, and, or

Tags: javascript, expression

I have been searching around but did not find any good solution yet, so what I am trying to do is I have below input Strings

```
(a&b|c)&d
a&(b|c)
(a&b)|(c&d)
```

so basically I want to validate if the input String is a valid logical expression, and below inputs  should return false;

```
a(b&c)
a(&b|c)
(a&b
```

So wonder is there a standard way to do this?

I tried this code
https://www.interviewkickstart.com/problems/valid-parentheses
but this do not cover all cases
`(a(&b&c))` will fail

Comment: Write a parser and an interpreter for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
function isValidLogicalExpression(expression) {
  let index = 0;

  function isOperand(char) {
    return /[a-z]/i.test(char);
  }

  function isOperator(char) {
    return /[\&\|]/.test(char);
  }

  function parseExpression() {
    let isValid = parseTerm();

    while (index < expression.length && isOperator(expression[index])) {
      index++; // Move past the operator
      isValid = parseTerm();
    }

    return isValid;
  }

  function parseTerm() {
    if (isOperand(expression[index])) {
      index++; // Move past the operand
      return true;
    } else if (expression[index] === '(') {
      index++; // Move past '('
      const isValid = parseExpression();
      if (expression[index] === ')') {
        index++; // Move past ')'
        return isValid;
      } else {
        return false; // Missing closing parenthesis
      }
    } else {
      return false; // Invalid character
    }
  }

  return parseExpression() && index === expression.length;
}

// Test cases
console.log(isValidLogicalExpression("(a&b|c)&d")); // true
console.log(isValidLogicalExpression("a&(b|c)"));    // true
console.log(isValidLogicalExpression("(a&b)|(c&d)")); // true

console.log(isValidLogicalExpression("a(b&c)"));      // false
console.log(isValidLogicalExpression("a(&b|c)"));     // false
console.log(isValidLogicalExpression("(a&b"));        // false
```